# Wrap 3rd party Interface to avoid dependence

Tags: java, interface

A third party library provides me with an Interface(this means I'm getting an object that implements that interface), let's call it `Config`. 
In my app I need all the functionality provided by this object through my own Interface in order to avoid its dependence to the 3rd party library, how can I wrap `Config` with `MyConfig` and just use the same object in my app? besides is it the correct approach to try to wrap the 3rd party library?

Comment: How can you avoid dependence on that library if you're still getting the object from that library?

Comment: think of it as your own framework and you want to use it in your new app, I want my framework to be tied to the library but not my app.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the 3rd party library to avoid compile-time dependency, but the 3rd party library must be there at runtime.

The easiest way would be to simply have delegating methods (IDEs can create these automatically):

```
public class DefaultMyConfig {
    private Config delegate;
    public MyConfig(Config delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }
    public String foo() {
       return delegate.foo();
    }
}
```

Of course, you can define an interface that is the same as the `Config` interface, and then implement it in `DefaultMyConfig`, or you can stay with a class only.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. How at runtime will the third party library can be used ?

Comment: In your app you can have one class that wraps the library and exposes it through your own interface to the rest of the application